# Wordpress Bookly Accept a Przelewy24 payment with Stripe

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

What should I do to change payment method in Wordepess addon Bookly/Stripe to Przelewy24 from card

I'm really not sure what to do.. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/p24/accept-a-payment?platform=checkout

Comment: I changed payment_method_type to p24 in wp-content/plugins/bookly-addon-stripe/frontend/modules/stripe/Ajax.php:, but it's not working

Comment: You'd probably want to ask the maintainers of that plugin if it supports P24 — it's something they'd have to build in, maybe they have settings to enable it, or so on. I doubt you can just hack the plugin code yourself to add it(at that point you'd build a direct integration with Stripe instead of using a plugin!)